# Как передать активность в класс extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-assets

Итак, у меня в `MainActivity` происходит инициализация БД:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = fDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Если базы нет, она создаётся через `onCreate()` класса `FDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper`. Но в самом `onCreate` база первично наполняется из файла, лежащего в `Assets`. И я вызываю внутренний класс, который работает с этим файлом и наполняет БД:

```
    FDbHelper.ExcelParser parser = new FDbHelper.ExcelParser();
    parser.fill(getAssets().open("file.xls"));
```

Раньше парсер работал у меня в тестовом режиме и вызывался прямо из `MainActivity`, и проблем с `getAssets()` не было. Теперь парсер вызывается из `FDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` и встала проблема, где взять активити или что-то подобное, чтобы добраться до `Assets`.

Comment: вам нужен Context (метод getAssets() принадлежит классу Context). Передавайте его из активити через конструктор класса FDbHelper при создании его экземпляра

Comment: Спасибо, как бы Ваш ответ теперь засчитать?

Comment: @pavlofff: прошу прощения, комментария вашего не видел, пока набирал ответ

Comment: @TimurVI Не за что извиняться :) Если бы я хотел написать ответ, я бы это сделал, а то что ответ написали вы, можно только приветствовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте передать Context классу FDbHelper, через конструктор

```
class FDbHelper{
Context context;

FDbHelper(Context context){
    this.context = context; 
      }

   FDbHelper.ExcelParser parser = new FDbHelper.ExcelParser();
         parser.fill(context.getAssets().open("file.xls"));      
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Так и поступил.